# How to create public method with CakePHP Users plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm on CakePHP 3.x using the CakeDC [Users](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.1.5/Docs/Documentation/SimpleRbacAuthorize.md) plugin to create simple role based authorizations.

I have a bunch of /admin/ routes which require login to access. I created a new action that I want to be public, but for some reason I keep getting sent to login. Here's my existing permissions.php:

```
return [
    'Users.SimpleRbac.permissions' => [
        # Admins can do anything
        [
            'role' => 'admin',
            'plugin' => '*',
            'prefix' => '*',
            'controller' => '*',
            'action' => '*',
        ],
        # Users can only see a list and view an item
        [
            'role' => 'user',
            'plugin' => false,
            'prefix' => 'admin',
            'controller' => '*',
            'action' => ['index', 'view', 'search'],
        ],
        # Only allow a user to logout within the CakeDC/User's plugin
        [
            'role' => 'user',
            'prefix' => '*',
            'plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users',
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => ['logout'],
         ],
    ],
];
```

Here's what I tried to add that *didn't* work:

```
        ...
        # anyone is allowed to do the .../dispatch method
        [
            'role' => '*',
            'controller' => '*',
            'action' => ['dispatch'],
         ],
```

What am I missing??

Comment: that means you allow that method for all authenticated users (all roles). If you want public method you should use $this->Auth->allow('dispatch'); as you already discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem had little to do with CakeDC/Users plugin at all. It seems that my "non-CRUD" action name was causing CakePHP do disallow it. I don't fully understand why. But when I added...

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('dispatch');
}
```

Everything worked as expected.